# How do you utilize the Theme values in the Flutter Package, json_dynamic_widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to work with the theme widget builder in the Flutter Package, json_dynamic_widget. I am on version: '6.0.5+1'.

To test it out, I was trying to access any of the default theme values, in this particular case, primaryColor.

However, I am unable to get it to pick up the value. I have tried the following.

Does anyone know the correct way to pull the value?

I have tried the following:

```
"color": "theme.primaryColor",
"color": "${theme.primaryColor}",
"color": "primaryColor",
"color": "{primaryColor}",
"color": "Theme.primaryColor",
"color": "{Theme.primaryColor}"
```

and if I have

```
{
    "type": "theme",
    "args": {
        "data": {
            "primaryColor": "#FF0000"
        }
    },
    "child": {
        "type": "text",
        "args": {
            "text": "Delete",
            "style": {
                "color": "{Theme.primaryColor}" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the color variable to pick up "#FF0000"

Answer (score 0):

Since these codes are static, you cannot access that data as it is. However, the functions you can use are defined here =>>  https://github.com/peiffer-innovations/json_dynamic_widget/tree/main/lib/src/components/functions